# How travel-ish do questions have to be?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I often work overseas for periods of a year or two & have long term residence questions which would not be applicable to holiday travellers.

Are such questions allowed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without seeing your specific questions, I'd guess that [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) is a better choice for them. Their [help center](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states:

> Expatriates Stack Exchange is for people living or intend to live abroad on a long-term basis, and for questions surrounding ordinary life, just complicated by your status as an expatriate.

That doesn't necessarily mean a question is off-topic here, but that needs to be judged on a case-by-case basis. Some questions you might have could actually be applicable for holiday travellers as well.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of it. Sounds perfect